# how add an element to form via jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/backend/basic/ticketRule/ticketAuditer/add"
            id="ticketAuditerForm" method="post">
            <table id="companyType_add_table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <th >Carrier：</th>
                    <td id = "ticketAuditerCarrierAddInit"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>user：</th>
                    <td align="left">
                        <input id="userNameAdd" name="auditer.userName" type="text" size="20" />
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <input name="search" type="button" value="select" onclick="searchUser()" /> 
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <input id="userIdAdd" name="auditer.id" type="hidden" size="20" value="3" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><p class="validateTips" align="center">...</p>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

then i want to add an  hidden element to form :

```
<input type="hidden" id ="ticketTypeId" name ="ticketTypeId" value="${1}">
```

jquery code:

```
$("#searchTicketAuditer").button().click(function() {
            $("#searchTicketAuditerForm").add("#ticketTypeId");
            $("#searchTicketAuditerForm").submit(); })
```

when i had submited the form ,i can get ticketTypeId from form, please help me！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the hidden element is already present in the dom then use `.append()`

```
$("#searchTicketAuditer").button().click(function() {
        $("#searchTicketAuditerForm").append($("#ticketTypeId"));
        $("#searchTicketAuditerForm").submit(); })
```

Answer (score 0):

If your element is already in the DOM and you want to append it to form you can use

```
$("#searchTicketAuditerForm").append($("#ticketTypeId"));
```

*`when you use append() that hidden button will cut and paste`

if you want to copy and paste you can use `clone()`

```
$("#ticketTypeId").clone().appendTo("#searchTicketAuditerForm");
```

if you do not have the element in the DOM you can use

```
$("#searchTicketAuditerForm").append('<input type="hidden" id ="ticketTypeId" name ="ticketTypeId" value="${1}">');
```